# How can I provide a custom client-authentication-scheme property for OAuth2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am writing a Springboot application that needs to authenticate users to an OAuth2 client provided by another group. The OAuth2 client provides two authentication schemes: `form` and `sso`. The application I am building needs to use the `sso` scheme because the application has no option to redirect the user to a login form.

Spring security contains an enum that provides the `security.oauth2.client.client-authentication-scheme` options that can be used, `sso` is not one provided so I need to be able to somehow extend this or provide a custom option.

Ultimately the application needs to generate a `GET` request that will take this form: `https://iapi.mycompany.com/authentication-service/v2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=myClientIdHere&redirect_uri=https:/myclient.mycompany.com/redirect&state=someStateString&login_method=sso`

As far as I can tell it's really only the `login_method=sso` part which is the custom part that needs producing. Any ideas on how I can convince Spring security to do this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the solution is to comment out the `security.oauth2.client.client-authentication-scheme` property in `application.properties` and to append `?login-method=sso` to the `security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri` property.

Final property looks like this:

```
security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri=https://iapi.mycompany.com/authentication-service/v2/authorize?login_method=sso
```